# SMTP-Mailing with PHP works - but not with PHP-Cli

Tags: php, email, smtp, command-line-interface, sendmail

I mentioned a strange behavior on my webpage: If I try to use Joomla to send Mails via SMTP it works fine; no problem at all.

But: If I try to use a PHP-CLI-Script the action fails (same source code).

```
            $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
            $config = JFactory::getConfig();
            $sender = array( 
                                $from,
                                $from 
                            );
            $mailer->setSender($sender);
            $mailer->addRecipient($to); 
            $mailer->isHTML(true);
            $mailer->Encoding = 'base64';
            $mailer->setBody($content);
            $mailer->setSubject($title);    
            $send = $mailer->Send();
```

If I do not use SMTP to send the mail but sendmail or php-mail, it works fine from PHP and PHP-CLI.

So my thought was, that there is possibly something in my php.ini for php-cli which blocks my cli-script from sending via SMTP.

Do you have an idea what to do?

Comment: My first idea is to look in the mailserver logs. Also my second, and my third.

Comment: Hm, these are the entries :-/ Not much I can read from them :-(

Jun 15 11:51:49 myserver nullmailer[2376]: Starting delivery: protocol: smtp host: mail.example.com file: 1434326633.1008
Jun 15 11:51:49 myserver nullmailer[2376]: Starting delivery, 4 message(s) in queue.

Comment: Ah, of course, there was an error: The server sends via another server (SMTP-Server, which is given in my Joomla-Installation, which runs the CLI-App).

Now it shows up, that the username is unknown in the virtual mailbox table. But of course it is, because the mail is delivered to the wrong server (test.example.com[193.xxx.xxx.xx] instead of mail.example.com). But the MX-Record for example.com is mail.example.com and not test.example.com.

Comment: Do you have a CNAME-Record for example.com?  Does A-Record for example.com poitns to the "another SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the path to php.ini passing option

`--php-ini FILENAME`

to the php executable.

Try again giving the path to the php.ini used by the webserver.

Comment: HI there, 

I tried that already - without success :-( If I run php -c /var/www/web1/conf/php.ini -r "phpinfo();" it shows me that the php.ini which is used by the web server is used.

Comment: that rules out differences in the php.ini config. Do you get some error message?